# how to sort name by last name from command line in java

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to write a program which sorts name by it's last name, first name when "sort" condition is applied. The input will be provided from command line. I have started this way but have no idea how to make it work.

**Input**:  sort "john main" "rob class" "bob ram"

**Output**: class,rob  main,john  ram,bob

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] args_name = new String[args.length-1];
    System.arraycopy(args, 1, args_name, 0, args.length-1);

    if(args[0].equals("sort"))
    {
        String firstName = name.substring(args_name,name.indexOf(" "));
        String lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(" ")+1);
        String slst = lastName + ", " + firstName;

        Arrays.sort(slst);

        for (String s: slst) System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your input coming from? what is `args_name`? what is `name`? Show the whole code. This code doesn't compile.

Comment: will you give list of names from CMD?

Comment: If you're reading names to be sorted from the command line, how do you distinguish between first names and last names?

Comment: i tried to distinguish by firstName and lastName inside if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a Comparator to sort your input. I removed your *args*-related code for the sake of simplicity. You will still need to re-add it properly.

**Required Imports**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
```

**The Name**

```
class Name{
    public static final String FULL_NAME_DELIMITER = " ";
    public static final String PRINT_DELIMITER = ", ";

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public static String[] getName(String fullName){
        return fullName.split(FULL_NAME_DELIMITER);
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.join(PRINT_DELIMITER , this.lastName, this.firstName);
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

**The Comparator**

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<Name>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Name a, Name b) {
        return a.getLastName().compareTo(b.getLastName());  // ASC: a to b or DESC: b to a
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class Main {
    // Holds the sorted names
    private static List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The input names
        String[] input = new String[]{
                "john main",
                "rob class",
                "bob ram"
        };

        // Prepare list for sorting
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String[] completeName;

        for (String fullName : input) {
            completeName = Name.getName(fullName);
            firstName = completeName[0];
            lastName = completeName[1];
            names.add(new Name(firstName, lastName));
        }

        // Actually sort
        names.sort(new NameComparator());

        // Print
        names.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To use the input from the command line, the *args* parameter is what you want to use.

**Usage with Commandline Input**

```
public class Main {
    // Holds the sorted names
    private static List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The method (in case something else than "sort" is desired)
        String method = args[0];

        // Check for valid method
        if(!method.equals("sort")) return;

        // The input names
        String[] input = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);

        // Prepare list for sorting
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String[] completeName;

        for (String fullName : input) {
            completeName = Name.getName(fullName);
            firstName = completeName[0];
            lastName = completeName[1];
            names.add(new Name(firstName, lastName));
        }

        // Actually sort
        names.sort(new NameComparator());

        // Print
        names.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

To use the first name instead of the last name, simply alter the Comparator.

```
class NameComparator implements Comparator<Name>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Name a, Name b) {
        return a.getFirstName().compareTo(b.getFirstName());    // ASC: a to b or DESC: b to a
    }
}
```

Of course, you would need to adjust the *Name* class as well, by adding:

```
public String getFirstName(){
    return this.firstName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I already did that now how will I print it vertically?

Comment: Try this: _for(Name name: names) System.out.println(name);_

Comment: Already tried gives list of names   [Brown, Kay, Long, Pam, Wong, Ann]
                                                      [Brown, Kay, Long, Pam, Wong, Ann]
                                                      [Brown, Kay, Long, Pam, Wong, Ann]

Comment: The only reason why a list would be printed, with the exact code I commented above, that comes to mind is a typo. Did you accidentally write _names_ instead of _name_ in the _println_ command?

Comment: The problem I am having is I don't want to print in list I want to print in vertical order. How to change "private static final List<ProcessNames> names = new ArrayList();" in order to print vertically not in the list format?

Comment: I made a mistake, update will follow in a few minutes - should be working as is then :-) EDIT: The problem was that I used _Arrays.asList(...)_ on _names_ which was a List already, sorry, don't know why I did that or why I didn't see that..

Comment: No worries, if I want to print in the same format but at last want to sort by first name instead last name how will I sort

Comment: You are still holding the sorted names on array list. How to get out of that

Comment: I want to print the output in vertical line do you have any idea please.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out :-) The names should be printed undearth each other when using the code as is :-) If you want them printed horizontally, use _print_ instead of _println_.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question well here is my code that solving this problem

```
public static void shortName(String shortName){

    System.out.println("please enter yout name : ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fullName = scanner.nextLine();

    if( shortName.equals("sort")){
        String [] nameArr = fullName.split(" ");
        int lastNameIndex = nameArr.length - 1;
        String name = nameArr[0] +" "+ nameArr[lastNameIndex];
        System.out.println("welcome : "+name);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("welcome : "+fullName);

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    shortName("sort");
}
```

Comment: input will be from command line: sort "john main" "rob class" "bob ram" Output: class,rob main,john ram,bob